# LAMP stack installation. Accidental deletion of ports.conf

Tags: 12.04, installation, lamp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to install Apache/PHP/MySQL with the 
default LAMP stack using `tasksel`.

Everything went well until I was going to edit the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file according to the [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Securing_Apache) guide. I unintentionally deleted the contents of the document because I had not first changed the file's permissions.

Now, I cannot figure out how to restore the file to its original state.

I tried reinstalling the programs, but it had no effect, as Apache is still installed and running.

Comment: [This should be set as the default content](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5878968/) for the latest version. You can try creating the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'd use the `apt-file` command (needs to be installed) to search for /etc/apache2/ports.conf: `apt-file search ports.conf`. This will provide a list of packages, one being apache2.2-common. So now you know which package provides the file you're looking to replace. Then you can either reinstall that package or download it and look at its content manually.

There might be better ways to accomplish it, but in general, this approach would always lead you in the right direction, at the very least.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have the problem fixed now... whew. :)